# REGEXP_LIKE for anything not like MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

What is the regular expression to be used to catch anything in the database which is **not** of the expression **MM/DD/YYYY**.
(I want everything which is apart from the above mentioned format, could be dd-mon-yy or yyyy/mm/dd etc)

I am using the below regexp query

```
select birth_date FROM table_name where not regexp_like (birth_date, '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]{4}');
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your query?

Comment: Though, that would accept values like 58/94/0987. Doesn't look like a valid date, eh?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,  a suggestion to you , don't use a `VARCHAR2 / CHAR` type for DATEs in database.

You may create a function using `TO_DATE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validmmddyyyy (p_str IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
   V_date   DATE;
BEGIN
   V_Date := TO_DATE (p_str, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;

select validmmddyyyy('09/12/2018') from DUAL;
1
select validmmddyyyy('13/12/2018') from DUAL;
0
select validmmddyyyy('2018/12/01') from DUAL;
0
```

Use your query like,

```
select birth_date FROM table_name where validmmddyyyy(birth_date) = 0
```

If you are lucky enough to use Oracle 12c R2, you could make use of `DEFAULT..ON..CONVERSION ERROR` clause of `TO_DATE`

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE TO_DATE (birth_date default null on conversion error,'MM/DD/YYYY') IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below query to get other than the required format :

select * from dual  where not regexp_like('2013/24/feb','[0-9]{2}.[[:alpha:]]{3}.[0-9]{4}')

Comment: Would match `999qzx99999` which is not a date.