# How to print record that caused ORA-01843 error?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, error-handling

I have a table with millions of records. I am trying to format one column data to `DATE` format
which is currently in `VARCHAR2`. But, I am getting `ORA-01843` not a valid month error.

I am trying to get those records which are causing ORA-01843

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_TEST_CUSTOM_ORA1843 AS

v_company MyTable.MyColumn%TYPE;

BEGIN
          BEGIN
              SELECT to_char(to_date(TRIM(MyColumn), 'YYMMDD'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
              INTO v_company FROM MyTable;    
          EXCEPTION
              WHEN OTHERS THEN
                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORA-01843 caused by'||v_company);
          END;


END  pr_TEST_CUSTOM_ORA1843;
```

But, the value of `v_company` is not printed.

How to get the records which are causing ORA-01843 error?

Comment: One method -- which is rather cumbersome -- is to write a function that converts the value one at a time.  Have it return `NULL` when there isn't a match and then look for `NULL` values in the output.

Comment: Seeing as your SELECT statement to populate v_company has just failed why would you expect v_company to contain anything? Maybe try outputting MyColumn instead?

Comment: Why do you need TRIM? Are there extra spaces in the values in that column? Then - what is the format of the strings in the column? Is it YYMMDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just commented on your previous question : [How to format only those records for which ORA-01843 is not thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773170/how-to-format-only-those-records-for-which-ora-01843-is-not-thrown)  but you did not pay attention to it.

Create a function which checks if it is a valid date like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validmmddyyyy (p_str IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
   V_date   DATE;
BEGIN
   V_Date := TO_DATE (p_str, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;
```

Then, to select the records which fail, you can run a query

```
select MyColumn FROM MyTable where validmmddyyyy(MyColumn) = 0
```

When you are lucky enough to use Oracle 12c R2, you could make use of `DEFAULT..ON..CONVERSION ERROR` clause of `TO_DATE`

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE TO_DATE (MyColumn default null on conversion error,'MM/DD/YYYY') IS NULL
```

An important advice as always, don't use a `VARCHAR2 / CHAR` type for `DATE`s in database.