# SELECT all the records with improper date format: Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In our oracle DB there are records which are not in a particular date format and I want to `select` only those record. For example.

```
Proper data format: dd.mm.yyyy mm:hh:ss
Improper date format: dd.mm.yyyy
```

Is there any oracle construct to select records based on date format?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dates are stored in an internal format, not as strings.  Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are they at the same table of different ones? So maybe you got date/dateTime used for saving some data. You just need to alter the type.

Comment: @LenglBoy: There are in the same table. I need to get the count of records which are not in a proper format.

Comment: So why do you not ask for counting entries by format?

Comment: @LenglBoy: Either way is fine.

Comment: If the date is stored in String format, you can check lengths and count based on that

Comment: Refer my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775696/how-to-print-record-that-caused-ora-01843-error/49776480#49776480 . Modify the function accordingly with the format u want.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that you are storing dates as a string (a very poor choice), then you can use a regular expression to come very close to what you want:

```
select (case when regexp_like(col, '^[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}$'
             then 'okay' else 'bad'
        end)
```

If for some reason you *have* to store dates as a string, use ISO/ANSI standard formats, such as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.

Comment: The OP & his date "format" fooled you, @Gordon. YYYY-**MM**-DDTHH: **MM** :SS? Two months in a date? I don't think so (and neither do you).